# Using different content-type in Flask Request on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post, flask, content-type

I'm trying yo pass a Content-Type to a flask app (running on GAE), But from python I cannot get the content type header even though I'm passing it

The server-side handler is the following:

```
@app.route('/api/handlers',methods=['POST'])
def color_list_post():

    if(request.headers['Content-Type']=='application/color'):
        logging.info('my-format')

    elif(request.headers['Content-Type']=='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'):
        logging.info('url-encoded')
    else:
        logging.info('wrong content-type')

    return ""
```

The header passed is:
    application/color

this is my request:
`curl -H "Content-Type:application/color" -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/handlers`

and this the error I get:

```
KeyError: 'CONTENT_TYPE'
```

Comment: The headers are case insensitive, but request.headers is a python dictionary, which uses case-sensitive keys. Check if the key you're looking for isn't actually `'Content-Type'` (or something else) instead of `'content-type'` by adding `logging info(request.headers.keys())` before your `if()` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I mistaken when adjusting the code for stack overflow, actually is everywhere 'Content-Type', but trying to print the dictionary it simply doesn't appear. It actually gives out: `[('Host', u'127.0.0.1:8080'), ('X-Appengine-Country', u'ZZ')]`

Comment: No more time for editing, the result above was for `request.headers.item()`, not for `keys()`

Comment: So that header doesn't make it to your app. To prevent the crash try `content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')` and use `content_type` into your `if()` statement.

Comment: FWIW, it could be from `flask` as I tried it on my plain `webapp2` app and I see it: `ERROR    2017-09-03 16:25:52,144 ci.py:157] {'Content_Length': '66', 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.42.1', 'X-Appengine-Country': 'ZZ', 'Content_Type': 'application/color', 'Host': 'localhost:8083', 'Content-Length': '66', 'Content-Type': 'application/color', 'Accept': '*/*'}`

Comment: Can you add a endpoint with `return jsonify(request.headers.items())`. Check it with both GET and POST and see what responses you get. As per documentation `Content-XXX` headers are passed untouched. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled